# Regex to return the first pattern match in a string

Tags: regex, xml-parsing

For the given xml formatted string

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Bond.CSharp" />
  </ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Bond.CSharp" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I am attempting to capture

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference
```

using the following Regex:

```
<ItemGroup>\s*<PackageReference
```

How can I limit the result to just the first match and not get both ItemGroups?

I am using C# flavored regex

I tried using

```
 (<ItemGroup>\s*<PackageReference)+?
```

and

```
<ItemGroup>\s*<PackageReference{0,1}
```

but neither approach worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.*` with the `Singleline` flag to consume all characters after the first match of `<ItemGroup>\s*<PackageReference` so that there won't be a second occurrence. Capture the desired portion in parentheses as a group:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(<ItemGroup>\s*<PackageReference).*", RegexOptions.Singleline);
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(xml);
foreach (Match match in matches) {
    GroupCollection groups = match.Groups;
    Console.WriteLine(groups[0].Value)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. Using SingleLine yields a single Match incl all PackageReference. Removing single line gives me 1 match but with Include=
```<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Bond.CSharp" />```

Comment: It works by adding ? after the .*  in your regex expression and removing singleLine. Thanks for your help.